# npm ERR! code HPE_HEADER_OVERFLOW npm ERR! errno HPE_HEADER_OVERFLOW npm ERR! request to

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, npm

While trying to install packages needed for creating react app, the following error appears.

PS C:\Users\Haseeb Cheema\Desktop\react-course> npx create-react-app my-app
npm ERR! code HPE_HEADER_OVERFLOW
npm ERR! errno HPE_HEADER_OVERFLOW
npm ERR! request to https://registry.npmjs.orgregistry.npmjs.orgregistry.npmjs.orgregistry.npmjs.orgregistry.npmjs.orgregistry.npmjs.orgregistry.npmjs.orgregistry.npmjs.orgregistry.npmjs.orgregistry.npmjs.orgregistry.npmjs.orgregistry.npmjs.orgregistry.npmjs.orgregistry.npmjs.orgregistry.npmjs.orgregistry.npmjs.orgregistry.npmjs.orgregistry.npmjs.orgregistry.npmjs.orgregistry.npmjs.orgregistry.npmjs.orgregistry.npmjs.orgregistry.npmjs.orgregistry.npmjs.orgregistry.npmjs.orgregistry.npmjs.orgregistry.npmjs.orgregistry.npmjs.orgregistry.npmjs.orgregistry.npmjs.orgregistry.npmjs.orgregistry.npmjs.orgregistry.npmjs.orgregistry.npmjs.orgregistry.npmjs.orgregistry.npmjs.orgregistry.npmjs.orgregistry.npmjs.orgregistry.npmjs.orgregistry.npmjs.orgregistry.npmjs.orgregistry.npmjs.orgregistry.npmjs.orgregistry.npmjs.orgregistry.npmjs.orgregistry.npmjs.orgregistry.npmjs.orgregistry.npmjs.orgregistry.npmjs.orgregistry.npmjs.orgregistry.npmjs.orgregistry.npmjs.orgregistry.npmjs.orgregistry.npmjs.orgregistry.npmjs.orgregistry.npmjs.orgregistry.npmjs.orgregistry.npmjs.orgregistry.npmjs.orgregistry.npmjs.orgregistry.npmjs.orgregistry.npmjs.orgregistry.npmjs.orgregistry.npmjs.orgregistry.npmjs.orgregistry.npmjs.orgregistry.npmjs.orgregistry.npmjs.orgregistry.npmjs.orgregistry.npmjs.orgregistry.npmjs.orgregistry.npmjs.orgregistry.npmjs.orgregistry.npmjs.orgregistry.npmjs.orgregistry.npmjs.orgregistry.npmjs.orgregistry.npmjs.orgregistry.npmjs.orgregistry.npmjs.orgregistry.npmjs.orgregistry.npmjs.orgregistry.npmjs.orgregistry.npmjs.orgregistry.npmjs.orgregistry.npmjs.orgregistry.npmjs.orgregistry.npmjs.orgregistry.npmjs.orgregistry.npmjs.orgregistry.npmjs.orgregistry.npmjs.orgregistry.npmjs.orgregistry.npmjs.orgregistry.npmjs.orgregistry.npmjs.orgregistry.npmjs.orgregistry.npmjs.orgregistry.npmjs.orgregistry.npmjs.orgregistry.npmjs.orgregistry.npmjs.orgregistry.npmjs.orgregistry.npmjs.orgregistry.npmjs.orgregistry.npmjs.orgregistry.npmjs.orgregistry.npmjs.orgregistry.npmjs.orgregistry.npmjs.orgregistry.npmjs.orgregistry.npmjs.orgregistry.npmjs.orgregistry.npmjs.orgregistry.npmjs.orgregistry.npmjs.orgregistry.npmjs.orgregistry.npmjs.orgregistry.npmjs.orgregistry.npmjs.orgregistry.npmjs.orgregistry.npmjs.orgregistry.npmjs.orgregistry.npmjs.orgregistry.npmjs.orgregistry.npmjs.orgregistry.npmjs.orgregistry.npmjs.orgregistry.npmjs.orgregistry.npmjs.orgregistry.npmjs.orgregistry.npmjs.orgregistry.npmjs.orgregistry.npmjs.orgregistry.npmjs.orgregistry.npmjs.orgregistry.npmjs.orgregistry.npmjs.orgregistry.npmjs.orgregistry.npmjs.orgregistry.npmjs.orgregistry.npmjs.orgregistry.npmjs.orgregistry.npmjs.orgregistry.npmjs.orgregistry.npmjs.orgregistry.npmjs.orgregistry.npmjs.orgregistry.npmjs.orgregistry.npmjs.orgregistry.npmjs.orgregistry.npmjs.orgregistry.npmjs.orgregistry.npmjs.orgregistry.npmjs.orgregistry.npmjs.orgregistry.npmjs.orgregistry.npmjs.orgregistry.npmjs.orgregistry.npmjs.orgregistry.npmjs.orgregistry.npmjs.orgregistry.npmjs.orgregistry.npmjs.orgregistry.npmjs.orgregistry.npmjs.orgregistry.npmjs.orgregistry.npmjs.orgregistry.npmjs.orgregistry.npmjs.orgregistry.npmjs.orgregistry.npmjs.orgregistry.npmjs.orgregistry.npmjs.orgregistry.npmjs.orgregistry.npmjs.orgregistry.npmjs.orgregistry.npmjs.orgregistry.npmjs.orgregistry.npmjs.orgregistry.npmjs.orgregistry.npmjs.orgregistry.npmjs.orgregistry.npmjs.orgregistry.npmjs.orgregistry.npmjs.orgregistry.npmjs.orgregistry.npmjs.orgregistry.npmjs.orgregistry.npmjs.orgregistry.npmjs.orgregistry.npmjs.orgregistry.npmjs.orgregistry.npmjs.orgregistry.npmjs.orgregistry.npmjs.orgregistry.npmjs.orgregistry.npmjs.orgregistry.npmjs.orgregistry.npmjs.orgregistry.npmjs.orgregistry.npmjs.orgregistry.npmjs.orgregistry.npmjs.orgregistry.npmjs.orgregistry.npmjs.orgregistry.npmjs.orgregistry.npmjs.orgregistry.npmjs.orgregistry.npmjs.orgregistry.npmjs.orgregistry.npmjs.orgregistry.npmjs.orgregistry.npmjs.orgregistry.npmjs.orgregistry.npmjs.orgregistry.npmjs.orgregistry.npmjs.orgregistry.npmjs.orgregistry.npmjs.orgregistry.npmjs.orgregistry.npmjs.orgregistry.npmjs.orgregistry.npmjs.orgregistry.npmjs.orgregistry.npmjs.orgregistry.npmjs.orgregistry.npmjs.orgregistry.npmjs.orgregistry.npmjs.orgregistry.npmjs.orgregistry.npmjs.orgregistry.npmjs.orgregistry.npmjs.orgregistry.npmjs.orgregistry.npmjs.orgregistry.npmjs.orgregistry.npmjs.orgregistry.npmjs.orgregistry.npmjs.orgregistry.npmjs.orgregistry.npmjs.orgregistry.npmjs.orgregistry.npmjs.orgregistry.npmjs.orgregistry.npmjs.orgregistry.npmjs.orgregistry.npmjs.orgregistry.npmjs.orgregistry.npmjs.orgregistry.npmjs.orgregistry.npmjs.orgregistry.npmjs.orgregistry.npmjs.orgregistry.npmjs.orgregistry.npmjs.orgregistry.npmjs.orgregistry.npmjs.orgregistry.npmjs.orgregistry.npmjs.orgregistry.npmjs.orgregistry.npmjs.orgregistry.npmjs.orgregistry.npmjs.orgregistry.npmjs.orgregistry.npmjs.orgregistry.npmjs.orgregistry.npmjs.orgregistry.npmjs.orgregistry.npmjs.orgregistry.npmjs.orgregistry.npmjs.orgregistry.npmjs.orgregistry.npmjs.orgregistry.npmjs.orgregistry.npmjs.orgregistry.npmjs.orgregistry.npmjs.orgregistry.npmjs.orgregistry.npmjs.orgregistry.npmjs.orgregistry.npmjs.orgregistry.npmjs.orgregistry.npmjs.orgregistry.npmjs.orgregistry.npmjs.orgregistry.npmjs.orgregistry.npmjs.orgregistry.npmjs.orgregistry.npmjs.orgregistry.npmjs.orgregistry.npmjs.orgregistry.npmjs.orgregistry.npmjs.orgregistry.npmjs.orgregistry.npmjs.orgregistry.npmjs.orgregistry.npmjs.orgregistry.npmjs.orgregistry.npmjs.orgregistry.npmjs.orgregistry.npmjs.orgregistry.npmjs.orgregistry.npmjs.orgregistry.npmjs.orgregistry.npmjs.orgregistry.npmjs.orgregistry.npmjs.orgregistry.npmjs.orgregistry.npmjs.orgregistry.npmjs.orgregistry.npmjs.orgregistry.npmjs.orgregistry.npmjs.orgregistry.npmjs.orgregistry.npmjs.orgregistry.npmjs.orgregistry.npmjs.orgregistry.npmjs.orgregistry.npmjs.orgregistry.npmjs.orgregistry.npmjs.orgregistry.npmjs.orgregistry.npmjs.orgregistry.npmjs.orgregistry.npmjs.orgregistry.npmjs.orgregistry.npmjs.orgregistry.npmjs.orgregistry.npmjs.orgregistry.npmjs.orgregistry.npmjs.orgregistry.npmjs.orgregistry.npmjs.orgregistry.npmjs.orgregistry.npmjs.orgregistry.npmjs.orgregistry.npmjs.orgregistry.npmjs.orgregistry.npmjs.orgregistry.npmjs.orgregistry.npmjs.orgregistry.npmjs.orgregistry.npmjs.orgregistry.npmjs.orgregistry.npmjs.orgregistry.npmjs.orgregistry.npmjs.orgregistry.npmjs.orgregistry.npmjs.orgregistry.npmjs.orgregistry.npmjs.orgregistry.npmjs.orgregistry.npmjs.orgregistry.npmjs.orgregistry.npmjs.orgregistry.npmjs.orgregistry.npmjs.orgregistry.npmjs.orgregistry.npmjs.orgregistry.npmjs.orgregistry.npmjs.orgregistry.npmjs.orgregistry.npmjs.orgregistry.npmjs.orgregistry.npmjs.orgregistry.npmjs.orgregistry.npmjs.orgregistry.npmjs.orgregistry.npmjs.orgregistry.npmjs.orgregistry.npmjs.orgregistry.npmjs.orgregistry.npmjs.orgregistry.npmjs.orgregistry.npmjs.orgregistry.npmjs.orgregistry.npmjs.orgregistry.npmjs.orgregistry.npmjs.orgregistry.npmjs.orgregistry.npmjs.orgregistry.npmjs.orgregistry.npmjs.orgregistry.npmjs.orgregistry.npmjs.orgregistry.npmjs.orgregistry.npmjs.orgregistry.npmjs.orgregistry.npmjs.orgregistry.npmjs.orgregistry.npmjs.orgregistry.npmjs.orgregistry.npmjs.orgregistry.npmjs.orgregistry.npmjs.orgregistry.npmjs.orgregistry.npmjs.orgregistry.npmjs.orgregistry.npmjs.orgregistry.npmjs.orgregistry.npmjs.orgregistry.npmjs.orgregistry.npmjs.orgregistry.npmjs.orgregistry.npmjs.orgregistry.npmjs.orgregistry.npmjs.orgregistry.npmjs.orgregistry.npmjs.orgregistry.npmjs.orgregistry.npmjs.orgregistry.npmjs.orgregistry.npmjs.orgregistry.npmjs.orgregistry.npmjs.orgregistry.npmjs.orgregistry.npmjs.orgregistry.npmjs.orgregistry.npmjs.orgregistry.npmjs.orgregistry.npmjs.orgregistry.npmjs.orgregistry.npmjs.orgregistry.npmjs.orgregistry.npmjs.orgregistry.npmjs.orgregistry.npmjs.orgregistry.npmjs.orgregistry.npmjs.orgregistry.npmjs.orgregistry.npmjs.orgregistry.npmjs.orgregistry.npmjs.orgregistry.npmjs.orgregistry.npmjs.orgregistry.npmjs.orgregistry.npmjs.orgregistry.npmjs.orgregistry.npmjs.orgregistry.npmjs.orgregistry.npmjs.orgregistry.npmjs.orgregistry.npmjs.orgregistry.npmjs.orgregistry.npmjs.orgregistry.npmjs.orgregistry.npmjs.orgregistry.npmjs.orgregistry.npmjs.orgregistry.npmjs.orgregistry.npmjs.orgregistry.npmjs.orgregistry.npmjs.orgregistry.npmjs.orgregistry.npmjs.orgregistry.npmjs.orgregistry.npmjs.orgregistry.npmjs.orgregistry.npmjs.orgregistry.npmjs.orgregistry.npmjs.orgregistry.npmjs.orgregistry.npmjs.orgregistry.npmjs.orgregistry.npmjs.orgregistry.npmjs.orgregistry.npmjs.orgregistry.npmjs.orgregistry.npmjs.orgregistry.npmjs.orgregistry.npmjs.orgregistry.npmjs.orgregistry.npmjs.orgregistry.npmjs.orgregistry.npmjs.orgregistry.npmjs.orgregistry.npmjs.orgregistry.npmjs.orgregistry.npmjs.orgregistry.npmjs.orgregistry.npmjs.orgregistry.npmjs.orgregistry.npmjs.orgregistry.npmjs.orgregistry.npmjs.orgregistry.npmjs.orgregistry.npmjs.orgregistry.npmjs.orgregistry.npmjs.orgregistry.npmjs.orgregistry.npmjs.orgregistry.npmjs.orgregistry.npmjs.orgregistry.npmjs.orgregistry.npmjs.orgregistry.npmjs.orgregistry.npmjs.orgregistry.npmjs.orgregistry.npmjs.orgregistry.npmjs.orgregistry.npmjs.orgregistry.npmjs.orgregistry.npmjs.orgregistry.npmjs.orgregistry.npmjs.orgregistry.npmjs.orgregistry.npmjs.orgregistry.npmjs.orgregistry.npmjs.orgregistry.npmjs.orgregistry.npmjs.org/ failed, reason: Parse Error: Header overflow

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     C:\Users\Haseeb Cheema\AppData\Local\npm-cache_logs\2022-10-03T11_09_41_720Z-debug-0.log

Comment: Can you probe it changing the `--max-http-header-size=16000` value increasing it

Comment: I tried but it didn't work

Answer (score 0):

I tried the following commands and it worked for me:

```
echo "" > $(npm config get userconfig)
npm config edit
```

Answer (score 0):

Try to reset your npm proxy settings using these commands:

```
npm config rm proxynpm
npm config rm https-proxy
```